# Redirecting Pipe Output in C++

Tags: c++, c, stream, pipe

I’m looking for a C/C++ way to execute a shell command and store the output of that command in a `std::string` or file, *without* the output being automatically printed to the console.

All approaches I’ve seen can do exactly that, but also print the execution result to the console.

For example with a combination of

```
FILE* pipe = popen("ls", "r");
```

and

```
fgets()
```

I’m able to do just that, but with the printing to the console.

Is there perhaps a way to redirect the stream’s buffer from std::cout to std::sstream, or has it semething to do with Ubuntu?

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: If you are using `popen` only `stdout` will be available in `pipe` (and it will not be printed on screen unless you do it yourself). I suggest taking a look at [boost::process](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/process.html)

Comment: In case you get error messages on the console, you can combine `stdout` and `stderr` by a shell redirection like `FILE* pipe = popen("ls 2>&1", "r");`

Comment: You both are geniuses! I didn’t realize I was getting errors from the shell => they were automatically printed. The 2>&1 part did it, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The 2>&1 part from the comments did it.